# Three.js source code of the laser-controls component

Tags: aframe

Where I can find the THREE.js source code of the component:
https://aframe.io/docs/0.8.0/components/laser-controls.html.

`<a-entity laser-controls="hand: left"></a-entity>`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The source code for the laser controls is [here](https://github.com/aframevr/aframe/blob/v0.8.0/src/components/laser-controls.js). 
It creates all controller models ([source](https://github.com/aframevr/aframe/blob/v0.8.0/src/components/laser-controls.js#L15-#L20)), and adds a raycaster ([source](https://github.com/aframevr/aframe/blob/v0.8.0/src/components/raycaster.js)).

The controllers utilize the [tracked-controls](https://github.com/aframevr/aframe/blob/v0.8.0/src/components/tracked-controls.js), where is the core source code.

Most of it isn't THREE (the raycaster mostly), depends what exactly are you looking for.

Answer (score 0):

There's a source link on all docs on the right:

[image]